# Incorporating a second parameter into recursion function and printing result

Tags: python, recursion, parameters

I'm trying to write a function to print a sequence of count steps recursively. The function prints count steps of the double plus 5 sequence from the start value.

I was able to figure out the general recursion for just the start parameter alone, but I cannot figure out how to include my second parameter count, for how many times the function should run, and how to have it print the result inside the function itself. (I have it printing outside currently)

Here is my current code:

```
def sequence_rec(start):
    if start == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return sequence_rec(start-1)*2 + 5


for start in range(1, 10):print(sequence_rec(start))
```

I want the function to use two parameters instead of just the one I currently have:

```
def sequence_rec(start, count):
    if start == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return sequence_rec(start-1)*2 + 5
```

I want the output to look something like this:

```
>sequence_rec(1, 2)

1 7 19
```

Current recursion work:

```
def sequence_rec(start, count):
    if count == 0:
        return
    else:
        value = sequence_rec(start * 2 + 5, count - 1)
    print(value)



sequence_rec(1, 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to wrap your recursive function in an iterative function that does the printing you want:

```
>>> def print_sequence(n):
...     for i in range(1, n+2):
...         print(sequence_rec(i))
... 
>>> print_sequence(2)
1 
7 
19 
>>>
```

In general it's good practice to have each function do one simple thing; this makes it easy to reuse your function by combining them in different ways.

That said, if you wanted the printing to be a side effect of `sequence_rec` you could simply do:

```
>>> def sequence_rec(start):
...     if start == 1:
...         ret = 1
...     else:
...         ret = sequence_rec(start - 1) * 2 + 5
...     print(ret)
...     return ret
... 
>>> sequence_rec(3)
1
7
19
```

(edit) The function you describe in your comments doesn't make sense as a recursive function since it's not moving toward a base case.  Try iteration instead:

```
>>> def sequence_iter(start, count):
...     for _ in range(count + 1):
...         print(start)
...         start = start * 2 + 5
... 
>>> sequence_iter(2, 5)
2
9
23
51
107
219
```

If you need to do it with recursion, the tactic is to decrement `count` each time:

```
>>> def sequence_rec(start, count):
...     if count < 0:
...         return
...     print(start)
...     sequence_rec(start * 2 + 5, count - 1)
... 
>>> sequence_rec(2, 5)
2
9
23
51
107
219
```

Comment: That does accomplish what I want the main function to do however (should've made this more clear in the initial post, I'll fix it) I want the function to use two paraments to accomplish the task like: def sequence_rec(start, count):

Comment: The `start` parameter already determines how many iterations it'll go through, so there would be no purpose to a second `count` parameter.

Comment: For when I want to start to be one, the function works. However, the reason I want to add a count parameter is for when I want it to be different. I.E: If I did >print_sequence_rec( 2, 5) The output would be: 2 9 23 51 107 219

Comment: That's not how your recursive function works, though.  It counts *backwards* from `start` until it reaches 1.  It would actually be simpler to write it as an iterative function but that's completely different from what you started with.

Comment: Added code for the iterative function to my answer.

Comment: That makes sense that I can't get it to work that way as recursive then, thanks for pointing that out. While the iterative function can be used in what I'm doing, I'm required to have it be recursive. Do you have any suggestions on how I should go about that?

Comment: Gross.  Probably by decrementing `count` in each recursive call and having the base case be `count == 0` instead of `start == 1`.

Comment: Yeah seems pretty gross, if it wouldn't be too much trouble I'll edit my post with what I tried for that if you have any ideas on what to do with it.